# ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular2-aot

Trying to build an Angular 6 app. I am getting the following error when using `--prod`

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Expression form not supported in 'reducers'
    'reducers' contains the error at app/app.module.ts(48,3).
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
      import AuthEffects from './store/auth/auth.effects';
        import ContentEffects from './store/content/content.effects';
        import NavigationEffects from './store/navigation/navigation.effects';
        import ConfigEffects from './store/config/config.effects';
        
        import { ICommonAppState } from './app.state';
        import { reducer as authReducer, key as authKey } from './store/auth';
        import { reducer as configReducer, key as configKey } from './store/config';
        import { reducer as contentReducer, key as contentKey } from './store/content';
        import { reducer as navigationReducer, key as navigationKey } from './store/navigation';
        
        import { PageContainerComponent } from './page-container/page-container.component';
        import { BenefitsComponent } from './+benefits/benefits.component';
        import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
        
        const enhancers = [];
        if (!environment.production) {
          enhancers.push(StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 10 }));
        }
        
        export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ICommonAppState> = {
          [authKey]: authReducer,
          [configKey]: configReducer,
          [navigationKey]: navigationReducer,
          [contentKey]: contentReducer,
        };
        
        const effects = [AuthEffects, ConfigEffects, NavigationEffects, ContentEffects];
        
        @NgModule({
          declarations: [AppComponent, NavigationComponent, PageContainerComponent, BenefitsComponent],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
            SharedComponentsModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
            EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
            ...enhancers,
          ],
          providers: [
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/content-manager/' },
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
            DiscoveryService,
            AuthService,
            JWTService,
            ConfigService,
            ContentService,
            NavigationService,
            TenantGuard,
            AuthGuard,
          ],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent],
        })
        export class AppModule {}
```

Line 48, where the error is being reported, appears to be

```js
    export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ICommonAppState> = {
      [authKey]: authReducer,
      [configKey]: configReducer,
      [navigationKey]: navigationReducer,
      [contentKey]: contentReducer,
    };
```

I am using Angular 6 with NgRX 6. I cannot understand why this is not working. I have followed the docs and my application builds just fine if I do not use the `prod` flag. However the build is bloated and slow, I would prefer an `AOT` build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same problem... try to use an injection token to provide the ActionReducerMap.

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ICommonAppState> = {
    [authKey]: authReducer,
    [configKey]: configReducer,
    [navigationKey]: navigationReducer,
    [contentKey]: contentReducer,
};
export const REDUCERS_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<ICommonAppState>>('App Reducers');
export const reducerProvider = { provide: REDUCERS_TOKEN, useValue: reducers };
```

and then use it like this

```
  imports: [
      ...
      StoreModule.forRoot(REDUCERS_TOKEN, { metaReducers }),
      ...
  ],
  providers: [reducerProvider]
```

And the AOT compiler should then hopefully be able to analyze the code statically (without excecuting it).

Answer (score 18):

I also faced the same error, and in my case, it was just a typo in my module. I had one comma "," in the module's provider's array. Try to remove the comma after contentReducer from your code.

Comment: Awesome answer! My problem was just a comma in wrong place. Thank you.

Comment: Saved me! Thanks!!

Comment: same case occurred to me :)

Comment: Thank you so much, happened to me as well.

Comment: Ace. The PWA migration added another , for me too. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 1):

or just change  "  [authKey]: authReducer,"   to  'auth': authReducer,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when attempting to use a UrlMatcher when AOT was enabled for the production build.

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: AppCodeMatcher,
    component: AppContainerComponent,
    children: [ ... ]
  }];
```

> AOT compilation does not support anonymous functions.

E.g. ES6 Fat Arrow function

```
() => {}
```

However this also means **default** exports are not supported. You must use named exports instead.

E.g. Instead of this:

```
export default function AppCodeMatcher(){ ... }
```

Do this:

```
function AppCodeMatcher() { ... }
export { AppCodeMatcher }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will solve when you remove comma "," from declarations in app.module.ts. and restart you code editor.